# Why do I have to malloc the buffer each time I call 'getline' on a new file pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, malloc, heap-memory

I have a daemon written in C that reads a file every `INTERVAL` seconds line by line and does some work on each line if it matches the criteria. I can't leave the file open since the file is being accessed and modified by another API, so this is a snippet of the code to show the issue:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define INTERVAL 5

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t len = 100;
    FILE *fp;
    char *line = NULL;
    line = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    size_t read;
    int iteration = 1;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("iteration %d\n", iteration++);

        fp = fopen("input.txt", "r+");
        if (fp == NULL)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
        {
            printf("line is: %s\n", line);
            // Do some more work with the data.
            // If the password has expired remove it from the file.
        }

        fclose(fp);
        if (line)
        {
            free(line);
        }

        sleep(INTERVAL);
    }
}
```

When running this code, it results in this:

```
iteration 1
line is: 1656070481 qwerty12345

line is: 1656070482 qwerty
iteration 2
line is: 1656070481 qwerty12345

line is: 1656070482 qwerty
daemon(37502,0x1027e4580) malloc: *** error for object 0x600003ca8000: pointer being freed was not allocated
daemon(37502,0x1027e4580) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
zsh: abort      ./daemon
```

So the problem is in this line:

```
if (line)
{
    free(line);
}
```

It looks like somehow the pointer is being deallocated somewhere inside the *while* loop. So, to solve this, I have to call the `malloc` function at the start of the `while(1)` loop to reallocate the memory with each iteration, like so:

```
while (1)
{
    printf("iteration %d\n", iteration++);
    line = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
```

This solves the issue, but I want to understand why the issue happened in the first place. Why is the pointer being deallocated after the second iteration?

Comment: The line you showed is the one that deallocates it. If you don’t want that to happen then don’t `free` the allocation in the loop. You allocate outside, you free outside. You allocate inside, you free inside.

Comment: In some cases, coding your daemon in [Rust](https://rustlang.org/) or [Go](https://go-lang.org/) or [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/) might be simpler and faster to develop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> have a daemon written in C

Then call [daemon(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html).

> so the problem is in this line:
>
> ```
> if (line){
>      free(line); }
> ```

Yes. So you need to clear `line` and code:

```
 if (line) {
     free(line);
     line = NULL;
     len = 0;
 }
```

On the next loop, `line` will be `NULL` and you won't (incorrectly) `free` it twice.

<sup>(I won't bother `free`-ing *inside* the loop, but this is just my opinion.)</sup>

Of course, before `getline` you want to allocate `line`, so before

```
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
```

code:

```
   if (!line) {
       line = malloc(100);
       if (line)
          len = 100;
   };
```

Consider using [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) and in some cases [Boehm conservative GC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector) (or my old [Qish GC](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/qishintro.html) downloadable [here](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/qish-snapshot.tar.gz)). You may then have to avoid `getline` and use simpler and lower-level alternatives (e.g., [read(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) or simply [fgetc(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html)...).

Read the [GC handbook](https://gchandbook.org/).

Perhaps use [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) on your source code.

(Consider also using [Rust](https://rust-lang.org/), [Go](https://go-lang.org/), C++, [OCaml](https://ocaml.org/), or Common Lisp/[SBCL](https://sbcl.org/) to entirely recode your daemon.)

On Linux, see also [inotify(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html).

Comment: Why do you say that, @SamiKuhmonen?  If it were my code, I'd probably set `char *line = NULL: size_t len = 0;` before the loop, leaving `getline()` to allocate the memory, and I'd have `free(line);` (without a null check) after the (infinite) loop to release the memory allocated.  Unless you're convinced that you can't carry the overhead of perhaps 256 bytes of allocated data between iterations, there's no need to free anything while the loop runs.  Check the POSIX specification for [`getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Because either allow it to allocate and have no allocation to begin with, or reuse the buffer. Having a mix doesn’t make sense to me at all, so the answer wasn’t really a good fix for the problem.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen — Your code was mixing up the control of the buffer. You can fix it in many ways — (1) giving `getline()` control of all allocation (but freeing outside the main (infinite) loop, or (2) preallocating space outside the loop and only freeing the space after the loop finishes, or (3) preallocating the space outside the loop, but resetting the freed space to a null pointer and zero size after the space is freed, or (4) preallocating the space inside the loop and freeing the space after it is used and setting the freed space pointer to null and size to zero.  All can be made to work.

Comment: Note what POSIX says: _The application shall ensure that `*lineptr` is a valid argument that could be passed to the `free()` function. If `*n` is non-zero, the application shall ensure that `*lineptr` either points to an object of size at least `*n` bytes, or is a null pointer._  When you called `free(line);` in the loop, you broke that contract — the value in `line` cannot be passed to `getline()` any more because the pointer cannot be passed to `free()` because the memory was already freed.  You have to stop breaking the contract, which you can do in many different ways — but not your way!